# Convert Python for loop with changing indexes into parallel operation

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

There are discussions about making statements parallel and many packages available (multiprocessing, joblib, etc.) and I cannot get this function to work in parallel.  I have a completely parallel function where processing order doesn't matter at all.  The function is an external C program.  All the inputs for each iteration stay constant except one, S[RFmap,i], so this subset of values is what has to be iterated over, as well as the output FEUPnL[i,:]. It seems a multiprocessing package should be able to do this without having to create each iteration before calling the function.  All I can imagine is there is something wrong with my initial setup.  Logic tells me somehow the S[RFmap,i] should be what I iterate over in multiprocessing, and possibly the FEUPnL[i,:] output has to be changed to accept a non-indexed result - anyone with experience please advise:

```
#original for loop
for i in range(0, 1000):
    FEUPnL[i,:] = Cfunction('p', FEU_callput, S[RFmap,i].tolist(), FEU_vol, FEU_strike, FEU_texpiry, FEU_IR, FEU_premium)
return FEUPnL


#version 1 attempt at parallel
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
FEUPnL[i,:] = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(Cfunction('p', FEU_callput, S[RFmap,i].tolist(), FEU_vol, FEU_strike, FEU_texpiry, FEU_IR, FEU_premium) for i in range(1000)))
```

pickle.dumps(function)
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

I've tried multiprocessing alone:

```
#version 2 attempt at parallel
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
i=np.arange(0,1000)
pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.map(Cfunction('p', FEU_callput, S[FEU.RFmap.values,i].tolist(), FEU_vol, FEU_strike, FEU_texpiry, FEU_IR, FEU_premium),i)
pool.close
pool.join
```

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (13410,) (1000,) 
Okay that one is more obvious, the i index for S[FEU.RFmap.values,i] can't take the 1000 length i index to it (but this index is required to get the right inputs from S for the parallel run).  Even if I try hardcoding 1 for i (which would kill my intended function), I get an error:

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.

Last, I've tried these methods to no avail: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/simple-python-parallelism/121
Someone with more experience, please assist!

```
#a guess where a fix may be needed, 'ITERABLE' is the S[RFmap,i] value I'm trying to insert
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.map(Cfunction('p', FEU_callput, `ITERABLE`, FEU_vol, FEU_strike, FEU_texpiry, FEU_IR, FEU_premium), S[RFmap,i].tolist())
```

Comment: Should this arg: `S[FEU.RFmap.values,i].tolist()` be `S[FEU.RFmap.values][i].tolist()`? Or possibly `S[FEU.RFmap.values].tolist()[i]`?

Comment: Apparently not... the RFmap itself is 15,000 fields which index 5000 fields from S.  The first suggestion above gives the same results - while it does iterate over S, it doesn't pass the S inputs back into the function (how do I get them in there?  wrapper function?)  The second suggestion gives the same error as in #2 above.